# I need help understanding the Nested Interval Property

Tags: real-analysis

In my textbook we have the theorem that

> For each $n \in N$, assume we
> are given a closed interval $$I_n = [a_n, b_n] = \{x \in R : a_n ≤ x ≤ b_n\}.$$ Assume
> also that each $I_{n}$ contains $I_{n+1}$. Then, the resulting nested sequence of closed
> intervals
> $$I_1 \supseteq I_2\supseteq I_3\supseteq I_4\supseteq \cdots  $$
> has a nonempty intersection.

What I am confused on:
Can you explain what $I_n$ is? Am I right in thinking that $I_n$ is a subinterval of the set of natural numbers?

Then by showing their intersections, you are saying that the subinterval of $n=2$ contains all of interval $n=1$, hence the nested sequence of closed intervals will never be empty?

Thank you.

Comment: $I_n$ consists of all real numbers between $a_n$ and $b_n$, as the definition in the textbook says. It does not only contain integers.

Comment: If you are in a class that is covering the nested intervals theorem and are unclear on the definition of an interval you should talk to your instructor ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

$I_n$ is a sequence of closed and bounded intervals.

- $n \in \mathbb{N}$, hence $n$ is a natural number, it is used to index the sequence of intervals.
- Now, let look at the  definition of $I_n$, $I_n = [a_n, b_n] = \{x \in \color{blue}{\mathbb{R}}: a_n \le x \le b_n\}$. From the set builder notation, we can see that $I_n$ consists of real numbers.

In this case, the interval shrinks as you increases your index.

For example, we can have

$$I_1 = [-1, 1], I_2=[-\frac12, \frac12], I_3 = \left[-\frac13, \frac13 \right]\ldots, I_n = \left[ -\frac1n , \frac1n\right], \ldots$$  and so on.

For my particular example, you can see that if you intersect these sequence of intervals, you get $\{0\}$. It is not empty.

Is it possible that someone can construct such a sequence of shrinking intervals and the intersection is empty? The theorem tells us that it is impossible.